# How to check/uncheck all the options in ion-select when checked/unchecked select all option in ionic3

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

Here is my code using which I want to check/un-check all the options in my select pop once the select all ion-option is checked/unchecked.

```css
items:any =[
      {id:1, value:"Apple"}
      {id:2, value:"Banana"}
      {id:3, value:"Stawberry"}
      {id:4, value:"PineApple"}
      {id:5, value:"Grapes"}
      ];
    selectedItems:any;
    selectAll:boolean;
    
    /**
     * This select all the items in the ion-select  popup
     **/
    selectAllItems() {
      if(!selectAll) {
        this.items.filter(Obj => {
          this.selectedItems.push(Obj.id);
        });
        this.selectedItems.push(0);
        this.selectAll = true;
      } else {
        this.selectedItems = this.items[0].id;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-item>
        <ion-label>Multiselect</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedItems">
          <ion-option (ionSelect)="selectAllItems()" [value]="0">
            Select All
          </ion-option>
          <ion-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
            {{item.value}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
```

When I use (ionSelect) the model is getting changed but the all the options are not getting checked and when I uncheck the ionSelect event is not getting triggered.
This is done in ionic-3. Anyone help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just insert in selected itens all ids of the itens

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone){
}

selectAllItems() {
    if (!selectAll) {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        for (let item of items) {
          this.selectedItems.push(item.id)
          this.selectAll = true;
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.selectedItems = [];
      this.selectAll = false;
    }
```

And at the select put the selectAll value

```
<ion-option (ionSelect)="selectAllItems()" [value]="selectAll">
            Select All
          </ion-option>
```

Comment: When I check the select all option only the select all option is getting selected and when I click on cancal button in the popup all the items are getting selected except the select all option. Could you help me out fixing this issue.